# SonarQube complains about an unused field annotated with @TempDir

Tags: java, sonarqube, junit5

I use JUnit 5 and I have a simple abstract class that serves as a test provider for its child classes:

```
abstract class TestProvider {

    @TempDir
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Path tempDir;

    protected void helpWithSomething() {
        // let's pretend it actually does something
    }
}
```

SonarQube complains because of the [RSPEC-2924](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2924) rule that states the following:

> This rule also applies to the JUnit 5 equivalent classes: TempDir, and TestInfo.

Surprisingly, the page offers a solution **without** any creation of such temporary folder, either using `@Rule` with older versions of JUnit or with `@TempDir` as of JUnit 5. Note the following snippet only removed non-compliant line with no alternative and compliant solution, which is kind of ridiculous.

```
public class ProjectDefinitionTest {

  @Test
  public void shouldSetKey() {
    ProjectDefinition def = ProjectDefinition.create();
    def.setKey("mykey");
    assertThat(def.getKey(), is("mykey"));
  }
}
```

I would expect at least a relevant compliant solution as this completely breaks the gist of the test. Note the `tempDir` is actually accessed with the child classes.

What is a correct and compliant usage of `@TempDir` according to SonarQube? Although I am aware of using a different suppression (`@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2924")`), I would like to know a compliant solution.

Comment: You can't tell statically whether `tempDir` is used by all the subclasses. You can instead define a temporary directory directly in the subclasses that need one.

Comment: It's probably worth raising a bug report to SonarQube. They should do a whole-project scan before emitting this sort of message.

Comment: @MikeFHay: Why cannot? It's possible to scan for the children and look for the variable usage. I see a gap here.